# Passing a value of combobox to a jframe from another jframe

Tags: java, combobox

I have 2 JFrames, one of which has a combo box. I'm trying to get the selected index of that combo box and pass the value to my other JFrame form.

I tried doing this: (in my NewJFrame.java)

```
int num = NewJFrame2.cmbNum.getSelectedIndex(); //NewJFrame2 = 2nd JFrame
```

so that I can do this:

```
if(num == 0)
//code
```

but I'm having an error on that line. (Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException)

I have no idea why because I really don't know how to pass values between 2 JFrames.

Comment: you'll need an instance of that other frame to get the value. it's just the same like with basic pojo's

Answer (score 0):

I would actually declare a static variable for this, so you can easily change the value anytime. Static variables can be accessed globally anytime from any source. They dont have to be initialized. They exist through space and time ;).

```
public static int num = 0;
```